# Why does changing animation layer make my model very small?

Tags: animation

I am selecting a certain animation layer, and my model becomes really small.

As it is hard to describe, I have uploaded a [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fWyp0wmuOw).

Does anybody see what might be going wrong here?
What could I check?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: its scale must be keyframed, you need to check this in the Dope Sheet, left panel > Object Transform > Scale tracks. Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Check that all transformations have been applied also

Comment: @moonboots Thank you. I have added the blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the action called *Genesis2Female|Animation|Base Layer* you can see that you've keyframed the XYZ scale of the armature itself:

[image]

You can see the keyframed scale in the *N panel > Item > Transform*, it has been set at 0.01:

[image]

When you open your file, we can see that the armature is set to a default scale of 1/1/1, so as soon as you select this action, the armature is scaled down to 0.01 of its size.

To fix that, select the action, select the 3 *Scale* tracks and press <kbd>X</kbd>.

The little bit confusing thing is that the armature transforms (location, rotation and scale) are part of an action, not only the bone keyframes.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I think that the little bit confusing thing is that the armature transforms (location, rotation and scale) are part of an action, not only bone keyframes.